# overcoming cross-origin restrictions for glfx.js/webgl

Tags: javascript, image-processing, webgl

I am trying to build a web application for real time image-processing. Specifically I need to be able to upload an image, perform contrast adjustments, gray scaling, edge detection and a connected component analysis on the image.

So far the only library I have found to at least support parts of this is glfx.js.

When I run

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/glfx-es6/dist/glfx-es6.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="image" src="lenna.png">
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            // try to create a WebGL canvas (will fail if WebGL isn't supported)
            try {
                var canvas = fx.canvas();
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
                return;
            }

            // convert the image to a texture
            var image = document.getElementById('image');
            var texture = canvas.texture(image);

            // apply the ink filter
            canvas.draw(texture).ink(0.25).update();
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the error:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The image element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded.

Any way to overcome cross-origin restrictions for webgl?

I tried to achieve something similar with opencv.js and node-opencv(https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv) but no success. I assume contrast adjustment would be too slow if it is not run on the client's graphics card however.

I might have missed other approaches though.

Comment: If you are running locally you [need to run a simple server](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-setup-and-installation.html)

Comment: Thanks, this worked.